# TSQL - Select every row from Table A - include field if there is related row in Table B

Tags: t-sql

I have 3 tables

```
Tags
TagID
TagName

Users
UserID
Username

UsersFollowingTags
UFTID
UserID
TagID
```

Many users can follow many tags.

I need a single SQL statement producing a result set that includes all tagID's & tagNames - and a field that says whether a UserID is following that tag.

I have tried left join - but if I include a WHERE userID = @userID - it doesn't output tags that the user doesn't follow.

The field indicating a related row could just be a bit - or the userID - flexible there.

thx

Comment: _"The field indicating a related row could just be a bit - or the userID - flexible there."_ Could you explain this further since it's not clear. It sounds different to _" a field that says whether a UserID is following that tag"_ Why do you want to add the `UserID` as column which is already the parameter?

Comment: @TimSchmelter not that important I think. Both your solution and mine answer to this "flexibility" problem, and avoid the "wrong" where clause. Now, yours is probably more efficient /elegant in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of putting the `userid=@userId` in a `where` clause, add this in the `left join` clause, and you will be fine.

If you put a `where` clause on a `left joined` table, this will do the same as an `inner join`.

so something like this if you want the maybe following username

```
select t.TagName, u.UserName
from Tags t
left join UsersFollowingTags uft on uft.TagID = t.TagID
left join Users u on u.UserId = uft.UserId and uft.userID = @userId
```

or if a UserID is enough

```
select t.TagName, uft.UserID
from Tags t
left join UsersFollowingTags uft on uft.TagID = t.TagID and uft.userID = @userId
```

or with a "bit"

```
select t.TagName, case when uft.UserID is null then 0 else 1 end as isfollowing
from Tags t
left join UsersFollowingTags uft on uft.TagID = t.TagID and uft.userID = @userId
```

Comment: _"...and a field that says whether a UserID is following that tag."_

Comment: @TimSchmelter `could just be a bit - or the UserID`, if you read further ;)

Comment: Ah excellent - I didn't realise you could use 'AND' in a left join. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CASE WHEN EXISTS`:

```
SELECT t.TagID,
       t.TagName,
       UserFollowing = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UsersFollowingTags uft
                                        WHERE t.TagID = uft.TagID
                                         AND  utf.UserID = @userID)
                        THEN 'Yes, user follows this tag'
                        ELSE 'No, user does not follow this tag' END
FROM dbo.Tags t
```

Comment: I wonder which would execute more efficiently this or RA's answer.

Comment: @niico look at execution plan : this one is probably slightly better, and more "expressive" for your case. I rather wanted to explain the problem with the WHERE clause with a LEFT JOIN .

Comment: Yes it is easier to read I'll give you that. I guess it comes down to personal preference.